# Please choose to register or to checkout as a guest pop show on Guest checkout in magento v1.9.3.7

Tags: checkout, magento-1, guest-checkout

After selecting a product and going to checkout page during the guest section, after clicking on continue, it shows pop up message which is:

**Please choose to register or to checkout as a guest**.

In backend section, guest checkout is enabled.

What is missing in this?

Comment: whats wrong in this?

Comment: @Piyush,after click on continue to select guest checkout , dialog pop box to show "Please choose to register or to checkout as a guest" message.